# Start a new search

Tags: search

Sometimes when I am searching I want to do a new search or maybe enter a command. I notice that if I press escape twice the current search is cancelled. I can then type "/" to start a new search. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: I need only to type <Esc> once to cancel the search. Do you confirm that you need to type <Esc> twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can press `<C-u>` to clear the `/` prompt, which allows you to type a new pattern.

See `:help c_ctrl-u`, under `:h cmdline-editing`.

Note that the whole topic *and that exact command* are introduced in chapter 20 of the user manual.